GLMM - similar estimated means across software but differing fixed effect estimates
I have run a GLMM using glmer (from lme4) in R. The fixed effects estimates are very different (much smaller) than expected in comparison to the estimated marginal means.
GLMM OUTPUT
`Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) \['glmerMod'\]
Family: inverse.gaussian  ( identity )
Formula: latency \~ Con_shape \* Cue + (1 + Con_shape | subject)
Data: SN_P_PMT_match_data_rt
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 

81984.2  82071.9 -40979.1  81958.2     6269

Scaled residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
\-3.1154 -0.6553 -0.1732  0.4628  4.9629

Random effects:
Groups   Name               Variance  Std.Dev. Corr  
subject  (Intercept)        1.718e+03 41.44726  
Con_shapeS vs. F   4.076e+03 63.84257  0.02  
Con_shapeS vs. Str 4.896e+03 69.97401  0.18 -0.57
Residual                    7.191e-05  0.00848  
Number of obs: 6282, groups:  subject, 42

Fixed effects:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(\>|z|)  
(Intercept)                       796.370     14.132  56.354  \< 2e-16 \*\*\*
Con_shapeS vs. F                   16.932     13.337   1.270    0.204  
Con_shapeS vs. Str                 95.656     15.344   6.234 4.55e-10 \*\*\*
CueSad vs Neu                      -3.186      4.045  -0.788    0.431  
Con_shapeS vs. F:CueSad vs Neu     -7.216     10.676  -0.676    0.499  
Con_shapeS vs. Str:CueSad vs Neu   -1.303     11.727  -0.111    0.911
-

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
(Intr) C_Sv.F C_Sv.S CSdvsN C_vFvN
Cn_shpSvs.F  0.088  
Cn_shpSvs.S  0.028 -0.271  
CueSadvsNeu -0.014  0.016  0.001  
C_Sv.F:CSvN -0.096 -0.099 -0.055  0.019  
C_Sv.S:CSvN  0.061  0.129  0.001  0.130 -0.548`

EMM
`Con_shape Cue       emmean       SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
self      sad     728.7943 13.14691 Inf  703.0269  754.5618
friend    sad     785.5311 13.31949 Inf  759.4254  811.6369
stranger  sad     811.8101 13.48155 Inf  785.3868  838.2334
self      neutral 733.1200 13.98504 Inf  705.7098  760.5302
friend    neutral 781.1784 14.08376 Inf  753.5748  808.7821
stranger  neutral 810.0302 14.53561 Inf  781.5409  838.5194`

Froom looking here I understand that fixed effects and EMMs may differ but I believe I have set the contrast coding so that coefficients should align with the EMMs. Due to this I am worried that there are issues in  the model. To check this I have run a GLMM in Jamovi which uses the GAMLj package and the coefficients are what I would expect and align with the EMM.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I am therefore wondering what is causing this difference please?
The variables are coded like this in R:
#Contrast coding - categorical variables (non-orthogonal)#
`contrasts(data$Con_shape) <- cbind("S vs. F"   = c(-.5,.5,0), 
                                            "S vs. Str" = c(-.5,0,.5))

         S vs. F S vs. Str
self        -0.5      -0.5
friend       0.5       0.0
stranger     0.0       0.5

contrasts(data$Cue) <- cbind("Sad vs Neu" = c(-.5,.5))

        Sad vs Neu
sad           -0.5
neutral        0.5`

This is the GLMM code:
`#Run glmer
model <- glmer(latency ~ Con_shape*Cue  +
                          (1+ Con_shape|subject),
                          data=data,
                          family=inverse.gaussian(link="identity"),
                          control=glmerControl
                          (optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))`

I am wondering whether the difference comes from using scaled contrast coding as opposed to unscaled (-1, 1, 0)?
I tried using unscaled contrast coding and this led to significant effects where expected when looking at plots from the EMMs but again very different coefficients (plus issues with singularity).
Unscaled contrasts
contrasts(SN_P_PMT_data$Con_shape) <- cbind("S vs. F"   = c(-1,1,0), 
                                             "S vs. Str" = c(-1,0,1))
 
 contrasts(SN_P_PMT_data$Cue) <- cbind("Sad vs Neu" = c(-1,1)) 

GLMM output
`Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: inverse.gaussian  ( identity )
Formula: latency ~ 1 + Con_shape * Cue + (1 + Con_shape | subject)
   Data: SN_P_PMT_match_data_rt
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 82171.8  82259.5 -41072.9  82145.8     6269 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0716 -0.6663 -0.1754  0.4809  5.3294 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name               Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr     
 subject  (Intercept)        1.734e+03 41.642073          
          Con_shapeS vs. F   5.894e+00  2.427823 1.00     
          Con_shapeS vs. Str 8.270e+02 28.758130 0.19 0.19
 Residual                    7.405e-05  0.008605          
Number of obs: 6282, groups:  subject, 42

Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                       786.600     13.085  60.113  < 2e-16 ***
Con_shapeS vs. F                   10.198      3.057   3.336 0.000851 ***
Con_shapeS vs. Str                 43.327      8.685   4.989 6.07e-07 ***
CueSad vs Neu                      -1.804      2.118  -0.852 0.394476    
Con_shapeS vs. F:CueSad vs Neu     -1.788      2.972  -0.602 0.547312    
Con_shapeS vs. Str:CueSad vs Neu   -0.504      3.137  -0.161 0.872377    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) C_Sv.F C_Sv.S CSdvsN C_vFvN
Cn_shpSvs.F  0.220                            
Cn_shpSvs.S  0.127 -0.150                     
CueSadvsNeu -0.004  0.001 -0.007              
C_Sv.F:CSvN  0.001 -0.009  0.013  0.009       
C_Sv.S:CSvN  0.013  0.012 -0.006  0.150 -0.574
optimizer (bobyqa) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')`


I would comment that unless you have only one factor in the model, interpretations of regression coefficients is complicated. And unnecessary.
It is also true that way back in the olden days, a very unfortunate choice was made to use the term "contrasts" for the method of creating dummy variables for factors. Often (but not always), the regression coefficients do comprise estimates of contrasts, but not always the ones that seem to be implied by the coding because of an inverse relationship between the dummy coding and the coefficients. In certain orthogonal codings, you are estimating comparable contrasts, but they are scaled differently.
But as I said at the outset, you really don't need to wade through those weeds. If you understand and trust the marginal means, those will give much clearer interpretations than the regression coefficients.
